# Cycle through docked applications in 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, ubuntu-dock

In older versions of Ubuntu, you could use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through the programs in the dock and open the one you landed on. Is it possible to restore this functionality in the dock present in Ubuntu 18.04, without switching back to Unity entirely? What I've already tried:

1. Under Keyboard, changed the application switcher to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> instead of the default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. However, I couldn't find any shortcuts there related to the dock.
2. Looking at `org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock` using `dconf-editor`, I found a lot of shortcuts for launching the 1st application, 2nd application and so on but having a separate number for each application is less ergonomic because my keyboard only has 1 Super key on the left-side and it seems a bit silly to use 8 different shortcuts for different apps instead of quickly cycling through them.

Comment: I just upgraded to 18.04 and I'm really missing that feature myself. I used it quite a bit to launch docked programs which seemed to be more productive than reaching for the mouse...