# Keyboard shortcut for launching application from dock in Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock

In Ubuntu 16 if you held down the <kbd>super</kbd> key, the applications in the dock display with a number. If you continue holding the super key and then hit one of those numbers, the application launches.

Is there a shortcut like this for Ubuntu 18?

Answer (score 18):

Simply press and hold <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. You should see numbers appearing next to the application icons. Then release <kbd>Q</kbd> and press the number associated to your target application to launch it.

You can alternatively press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> directly to launch the application without pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> first.

**Notes:**

1. If pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> fails to show the numbers, run the following command first.

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false
   ```
2. This shortcut only works with the keyboard’s top row number keys, not those of the numpad. You can install a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [AppKeys](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/413/dash-hotkeys/) to make it work with the numpad too.

Comment: In 16.04, you could cycle through/select the apps on the dock by pressing the `Super`+`Tab` key combo, which seems to be missing/disabled in 18.04. Is there a way to get that back? The same is asked here too without an answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060949/cycle-through-docked-applications-in-18-04

Answer (score 2):

### Dash to Dock

A dock for the Gnome Shell. This extension moves the dash out of the overview transforming it in a dock for an easier launching of applications and a faster switching between windows and desktops. Side and bottom placement options are available.

**Extension Homepage** https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/

**Install:**

- Install tweaks

  ```
  sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
  ```
- Goto the [gnome-shell-extension homepage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) and click the switch **on**.

**Configure keyboard shortcuts:**

Open the configuration, open **gnome-tweaks**, click on the left tab **Extension** and search the **Dash to Dock**. Click on **Configure Icon** and go to the tab and enable as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same as my answer? And my answer doesn't require GNOME Tweaks.

Comment: @heynnema I don't understand why both of you are suggesting installing an extension while it's an inbuilt (and activated by default) feature of the Ubuntu Dock shipped by default (as it's a fork of Dock to Dock).

Comment: @pomsky Edit: You're right, the inbuilt function is exactly the same but I think the extension gives you a few more appearance tweaks...

Answer (score 0):

Install the `Dash to Dock` GNOME extension, and modify the settings to do this...

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and `Dash to dock`, but it didn't work even the extension was configured like in @abu_bua's answer.

I used this two methods to fix it

1. Go to extension settings and switch the setting *off* and *on* again.
2. Another, simper and faster way was to run

   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys true

EDIT:
After some time I realized that this solution #2 above doesn't always work, but luckily the `Dash to dock` had no advatage for me, so you can turn it off and the shortcuts will start working. *Luckily it seems that you can configure the native dock with it.*